# Upgraded Coldfusion from 9.0 to 9.0.1 - new cfgrid problems in Firefox

Tags: firefox, coldfusion

After running into problems with auto-suggest stripping off leading zeroes, I took the plunge and updated my dev copy of CF to 9.0.1, including the cumulative hot-fix. Now I see a new problem.

Every one of my existing cfgrids is now displaying incorrectly in Firefox 6.0.2. The .x-panel, .x-panel-bwrap, .x-panel-body classes have a computed width of 12px, and are basically unviewable. I find that if I insert a css rule on those classes like so:

```
.x-panel, .x-panel-bwrap, .x-panel-body { width: 100% !important; }
```

the grids are again viewable. I did clear the browser cache to make sure it was importing the correct files.

IE8 and Chrome both seem to be unaffected.

Comment: report the bug to: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: What Henry says - **[tell Adobe, not us!](http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html)** - and since you've already worked out a workaround, go ahead and add it as the answer - you are allowed to answer your own questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Peter, why not? My workaround, as posted in my question, is to add the following css rule:

```
.x-panel, .x-panel-bwrap, .x-panel-body { width: 100% !important; }
```